# Python 3.4.3 ctypes: Trying to pass a structure to a function as an output parameter fails

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

Here's what I was given by the vendor to describe the function.

```
typedef struct
{
   float    distance_sm;
   float    distance_nm;
   short    fuel_stops;
   char     flight_time[8];
   char     block_time[8];
   char     departure_time[8];
   char     departure_date[12];
   char     arrival_time[8];
   char     arrival_date[12];
   char     timezone_change[8];
   char     messages[FOSAPI_MSG_LEN];
} FOS_LEG;

FOS_EXTERN_C bool DLL_EXP_UTIL fos_calc_flight(
   char *leg_date,               // in: leg date                          (
   char *leg_time,              // in: leg time                          (
   char *airport_from,          // in: from airport ICAO(4) or IATA(3)   (KOKC)
   char *airport_to,            // in: to airport ICAO(4) or IATA(3)
   char *aircraft_type,         // in: character aircraft type (max len = 4)
   FOS_LEG  *fos_leg,            // in: allocated space for FOS_LEG
   char errors[FOSAPI_MSG_LEN],         // in: 256 bytes  out: error messages
   bool arrival_date_time=false,    // in: true = leg_date and leg_time are arrival, calculate departure
   char *airport_from_prefix=NULL,  // in: from airport icao code(2)
   char *airport_to_prefix=NULL);   // in: to airport icao code(2)
```

So here's my code that I'm trying to access the function with. It seems that the problem is with the way that I'm trying to pass the structure as an output parameter to the function.

```
import ctypes

mydll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\FOS\\FosUtil.dll")

class FOS_LEG(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("distance_sm",     ctypes.c_float),
    ("distance_nm",     ctypes.c_float),
    ("fuel_stops",      ctypes.c_short),
    ("flight_time",     ctypes.c_char),
    ("block_time",      ctypes.c_char),
    ("departure_time",  ctypes.c_char),
    ("departure_date",  ctypes.c_char),
    ("arrival_time",    ctypes.c_char),
    ("arrival_date",    ctypes.c_char),
    ("timezone_change", ctypes.c_char),
    ("messages",        ctypes.c_char)]

fos_leg   = ctypes.POINTER(FOS_LEG)
error_out = ctypes.c_char

mydll._fos_calc_flight("04042014","0800","KOKC","KATL","H25B",fos_leg,error_out,1,"AP","AP")
```

Here's the error that is returned.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 28, in
>   
>       mydll._fos_calc_flight("04042014","0800","KOKC","KATL","H25B",fos_leg,er
>   ror_out,1,"AP","AP") ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 6: : Don't know how to convert  parameter 6

Thanks very much for the assistance

Comment: You need to pass the allocated space for the class. You only pass a pointer to the class. Try: `fos = FOS_LEG();` and pass `ctypes.addressof(fos)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but your structure should be more like:

```
class FOS_LEG(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("distance_sm",     ctypes.c_float),
    ("distance_nm",     ctypes.c_float),
    ("fuel_stops",      ctypes.c_short),
    ("flight_time",     ctypes.c_char * 8),
    ("block_time",      ctypes.c_char * 8),
    ("departure_time",  ctypes.c_char * 8),
    ("departure_date",  ctypes.c_char * 12),
    ("arrival_time",    ctypes.c_char * 8),
    ("arrival_date",    ctypes.c_char * 12),
    ("timezone_change", ctypes.c_char * 8),
    ("messages",        ctypes.c_char * FOSAPI_MSG_LEN)]
```

Next you should declare the arguments and return type of your function:

```
mydll._fos_calc_flight.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.POINTER(FOS_LEG),ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_bool,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p]
mydll._fos_calc_flight.restype = ctypes.c_bool
```

Finally, your output parameters need to be *instances* of the types required.  `POINTER` only declares a type, so you want to create an instance of the structure:

```
fos_leg = FOS_LEG()
```

`error_out` needs to be a writable string:

```
error_out = ctypes.create_string_buffer(FOSAPI_MSG_LEN)
```

Then call the function with a reference to the structure:

```
mydll._fos_calc_flight(b"04042014",b"0800",b"KOKC",b"KATL",b"H25B",ctypes.byref(fos_leg),error_out,1,b"AP",b"AP")
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it now complains that FOSAPI_MSG_LEN is not defined when I use that in the structure. Do I need to declare that beforehand somehow?

Comment: @AdamvonNieda, of course.  You didn't provide a definition in the C code, but from your comments in the code you can use `FOSAPI_MSG_LEN = 256`.

Comment: @Mark - Got it, thanks - What I get now is     mydll._fos_calc_flight.argtypes = [c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_cha
r_p,POINTER(FOS_LEG),c_char_p,c_bool,c_char_p,c_char_p]
NameError: name 'c_char_p' is not defined

Comment: @AdamvonNieda, It's defined in the `ctypes` module.  Precede with `ctypes.c_char_p` or `from ctypes import c_char_p`.  I updated the code, but as I said this is untested and just pointing out gaps.

Comment: OK, understood. Bear with me, please Now it tells me that argument 1 is the wrong type. We're defining it as a "ctypes.c_char_p" to match the functions "char", and passing it "04042014". I don't see why it would give that error?

Comment: Got past the invalid type by encoding the values - Example - "KOKC",encode('utf-8')

Comment: @AdamvonNieda, In Python 3, `"xxx"` is a Unicode string, more like `wchar_t` in C.  `b"xxx"` is the syntax for a byte string, which should be used for `c_char_p`.  `.encode` is used to convert a Unicode string to a byte string, as you found, but start with a byte string and you won't need it.